# Tensorflow: TypeError: 'RepeatDataset' object is not callable - why

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, typeerror

**Here is my model:**

starts at line: 39

```
def make_input_fn(data_df, label_df, num_epochs=10, shuffle=True, batch_size=32):
def input_function():
    ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((dict(data_df), label_df))
    if shuffle:
        ds = ds.shuffle(1000)
    ds = ds.batch(batch_size).repeat(num_epochs)
    return ds()
return input_function()
```

`train_input_fn = make_input_fn(dftrain, y_train)`

ends at line: 49

**Here is my error:**

`Traceback (most recent call last): File, line 49, in <module> train_input_fn = make_input_fn(dftrain, y_train) File, line 46, in make_input_fn return input_function() File, line 45, in input_function return ds() TypeError: 'RepeatDataset' object is not callable`

Comment: I don't think `ds` is a callable. Change `return ds()` to `return ds`

Comment: Thanks - I tried that. I seem to get another detailed error that ends with 
"AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.tools.docs.doc_controls' has no attribute 'inheritable_header'

Answer (score 0):

The Variable `ds` is not callable, Try to change `return ds()` in the `input_function()` to `return ds`.

 These types of error usually occur when you try to index an Integer or Float variable or you try to make a variable callable using `()`

 For Example

> var=10 
> print(var()) 
> var2=15 
> print(var2[0])

The above is the simplified example of what error you are getting.